# Why SELECT is so slow

Tags: mysql, performance, debian, query-performance

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `text` int(11) NOT NULL,
  w1 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w2 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w3 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w4 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w5 int(11) NOT NULL,
  w6 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w7 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w8 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w9 int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY w1 (w1),
  KEY w2 (w2),
  KEY w3 (w3),
  KEY w4 (w4)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

that contains **2,124,377,011** rows.

Why this simple query

```
SELECT w1 FROM words WHERE w2=3112
```

takes **50 sec** on Intel Xeon E3-1230 v2 at 3.30 Ghz Server with 7200 RPM HDD?

Is this normal or am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** It returns 60243 rows, the execution plain is

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | words | ref  | w2            | w2   | 4       | const | 31132 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: How many rows have `w2=3112`?  And how the query plan looks like?

Comment: See in the update, please

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo, but the table definition is about `words` while the plan about table `w`.

Comment: It's because the original query was SELECT w1 FROM words w WHERE w.w2=3112. I think it doesn't matter, right?

Comment: No, it shoudn't :)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  My understanding is that early versions would use only one index per table, per query, so being unable to scan the `w1` and `w2` keys and merge *those*, it would instead have to do a table scan.  How long does it take to `SELECT w2 FROM words WHERE w2 = 3112`, referencing only a single indexed column?

Comment: MySQL 5.5.43-0+deb7u1. Is it an early version? But you're right SELECT w2 FROM words WHERE w2 = 3112 takes 0.02

Comment: You are using MyISAM, whose most of its performance relays on the filesystem cache doing the right thing (not a very advanced storage engine), plus the number or rows returned is relatively high and the table large for this obsolete technology. Try executing the same query several times and provide the measured latency, plus show your configuration file.

Comment: @jynus so what technology would you recommend here?

Comment: @Mike It is very difficult to recommend a specific technology without a deeper understanding of your whole system, so I just remarked that MyISAM may be not very suited. Looking at the table structure and the additional information provided, maybe you could have a look at search technologies like Sphinx or any Lucene-based one. Definitely not a one-line answer, as it depends on how dynamic it is, other queries, etc.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades - "Index Merge" was added in version 5.0.  But even in 5.6 it is rarely used.  This is because it is rarely useful.  And composite indexes (eg, `INDEX(w2,w1)`) are almost always better.

Comment: MyISAM vs InnoDB -- Each will need to do 60243 lookups to find w1.  That might be 60243 disk hits or it might be a few -- depending on how scattered the necessary rows are.  (With 2.1B rows, I am assuming the buffer_pool / key_buffer / OS cache is not very useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is slow because the table is big, and it performs lots of IO when reading sparse data. The index on `w2` would be used to tell which rows will be read from the base table, which is huge. And since the rows in that table are not in order- physically that are fragmented, there will be probably one disk access per row (This is to read the value of `w1`)
- To make this query faster, create a composite index on (w2, w1). This way, the data is only read from the index file, which is much smaller in size, and the required data is adjacent.
- Note please that if it is not a frequent query, it is an overhead to have this index.

Comment: The problem is that I will need to run similar queries against different w* fields, so it's impossible to create all possible indexes :) What database/engine would handle this?

Comment: It is not practical to create indexes of all possible combinations. It all depends on the requirements. You may want to revise the design, or maybe give a try to TokuDB engine. You may also limit your returned result, so you have less data to be read from the disk. i.e. use `LIMIT 10` to test

Comment: Sure, it is impractical to "index all combinations", but a few combinations may go a long way toward helping.  If you add `(w2,w1)`, get rid of `(w2)` since it will be redundant.