# Why MySQL SELECT performance depends on table size?

Tags: mysql, myisam, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I've got two identical tables with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `text` int(11) NOT NULL,
  w1 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w2 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w3 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w4 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w5 int(11) NOT NULL,
  w6 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w7 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w8 int(11) NOT NULL, 
  w9 int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY w1 (w1),
  KEY w2 (w2),
  KEY w3 (w3),
  KEY w4 (w4)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

The first one contains 100M rows and the second one 300M rows. The following query

```
SELECT id FROM words WHERE w2=3112
```

- takes **0.16 sec** for the first (smaller) table
- and **20 sec** for the second (that is just three times bigger)

Why the difference in timings is so huge? Is there any configuration setting that I can change to improve it?

The execution plains are the following:

1st table:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wd3   | ref  | w2            | w2   | 4       | const | 2050 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

2nd table:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wd2   | ref  | w2            | w2   | 4       | const | 7440 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Please show us your table structures including which indexes you have and the execution plans.

Comment: Everything is here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100520/why-select-is-so-slow

Comment: Questions should be self-sufficient. Why ask a new one?

Comment: It's another question. Here I ask why is performance so much dependent on the table size and how to fix it?

Comment: MyISAM in 2015? Have we travelled 20 years back in time?

Comment: Why don't you change the engine type? MyISAM is fairly near end of life anyway - at least according to the MySQL dev team - from [here](http://www.mysqlserverteam.com/the-mysql-5-7-5-milestone-release-is-available/) "The system tables are being moved from MyISAM to InnoDB, so in 5.7+ it will be not possible to run the MySQL server without InnoDB".

Comment: Please run `SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @totalrows FROM words;` and `SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @w23112count FROM words WHERE w2=3112;` and tells us what `@totalrows` and `@w23112count` are for both the small and large tables.

Comment: They are (100000000, 2515) and (300000000, 7608) respectively. But actually I'm coming to a conclusion that it is some kind of caching that results in such a effect.

Comment: @Vérace so you advise to switch to InnoDB? Are there any other possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I realized that it was some king of caching and probably on Linux level.

After applying `# sync && echo 3 | tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` followed by `mysql> RESET QUERY CACHE;` the query time became linear.

Note though, that before this the effect was stable on different queries.

Comment: There is also MySQL caching.  You need 2515 or 7608 rows from the BTree-organized index.  This would be only a few dozen 1KB blocks in the key_buffer (re: `key_buffer_size`).  But then you need up to 2515 or 7608 data blocks (cached, or not, by the OS) to get the ids.  If the data is scattered enough, and the cache is cold, I would expect up to 76 seconds for the larger resultset.  (Table size is mostly irrelevant in _this_ discussion.)